# IE 8 transparent div with content on top

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, render, letters

Hi all
I'm currently having some issues with IE < 9 and transparency rendering.
I have a transparent div and some text over it. it looks fine in Firefox Chrome and IE 9.
however, the older versions of IE don't render the text as well as the other browsers.
It's readable, but the letters have some weird aliasing on the edges...

this is the website -->http://jmia-js.saude.azores.gov.pt

if you visit it using IE8 for example, you'll see what I mean. or ou can even use
IE net renderer to render the site in a IE8 browser.

does anyone know how to solve this minor bug?
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: i tried with IE 9, 8 and 7...i can't find the problem...can you be more specific about the block that is having issues ?

Comment: The text XXXVII and the text below that, looks odd in IE8 and 7. I just tired it with IE6 and it looks OK, although the page is not rendered 100% corectly, but that's another issue

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is caused by the CSS filter attribute you're using to get that transparency in IE. Try using a transparent PNG as the background instead and your type should anti-alias correctly.

Comment: good idea. I'll try that as soon as I can. do you  know if this sollution works with most browsers? 
thanks!

Comment: Renato, the PNG should work for IE7+, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, etc. IE6 does not support PNG-24 with full alpha so you'll need to make an exception in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of IE got an alternative way to read the opacity. Try adding this line:

```
.opaque {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
}
```

Comment: I already use that approach. The code for transparent divs is:
`.transparent{
  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.6;
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.6;
  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
}`
EDIT: I can't figure how to display code correctly.... lol